# Is there a way to stop the c# metadata from showing when navigating to a class or method in a VB.NET project from a C# project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So the scenario is this;

I have a VB.NET project and a C# project in the same VS2010 solution. The VB.NET project is referenced (and used) by the C# project as a project reference. If while I am in the C# project, and I Ctrl-Click or Go to Definition on an element that is part of the VB project, it takes me to C# generated metadata instead of the actual VB code file.

Is there any way to get this to go to the VB code file, so I dont have to navigate manually in solution explorer/navigator?

Comment: How is the vb project referenced by the C# project?

Comment: Are you sure it's definitely a project reference, and not a reference directly to the generated DLL?

Comment: Back when I worked in VB and C#, I remember hating this.  Even though they were project references, when going to definition from C# to VB, it would only show the metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no way to get "Goto Definition" to navigate between projects of different languages.  The problem is not just limited to C# and VB.Net but extends to other managed languages like F# and C++/CLI.  Each language sees the other as a DLL reference and hence you get metadata.

This is a known issue and something the language teams are well aware of.  It's usually high on the list of potential items for future versions of Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

You could try (CTRL + comma) which is 'Navigate to' as a workaround?

Comment: Thanks, but no dice. I dont know if it matters what key binding is used.

Comment: @StingyJack The key bindings do matter, of course: the command is called `Edit.NavigateTo` in the keyboard binding options.

Comment: That's not bound by default in the "General Development" settings, but I added it and I see what you mean. It still requires a search wait and clicking through some extra screens, but I'll see if I can get used to it.